# Session Variables being remembered after Session.Abandon (IE 11 only)

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, internet-explorer-11

I have an asp.net session that returns previously saved data after a Session.Abandon and Session.Contents.RemoveAll have been applied. Note: This only happens on a single computer running Windows 7 with IE 11. The session variables drop as desired on other IE browsers and Chrome. Also, my development box is running IE 11 and it works fine here. Just this one system seems to have a session ghost.

The code uses a session variable to track an anonymous user that visits the site to provide content. Multiple users may use the same computer so I set up a "change user" routine that Abandons the session and redirect the browser back to the default.aspx page where a login popup requests the new information.

But what results is that every page the "previous user" accessed shows the old user's credentials. Every other page viewed displays the "current user's" credentials. I use one single session variable to track the user through all of these pages.

Change User:

```
//Drops session and forces user back to default.aspx to be logged in.
protected void Change_User(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.Contents.Abandon();
    Session.Contents.RemoveAll(); 
    Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
}
```

This sounds like an IE 11 configuration problem to me. But I have never seen a session variable attach itself to a single URL.

Comment: You're sure it isn't a caching issue of the page(s) previously accessed by another user?

Comment: The user's browser was set to "never" check for newer versions of stored pages. That seems to have been keeping the old values alive. Mystery solved! Thanks!

Comment: Well there you go! I'll put that comment into an actual answer so it can be accepted and this question won't show up as unanswered anymore. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a shared machine between multiple users, it sounds as though the page(s) might be cached locally. Ask the user to try a hard refresh (`CTRL+F5`) to confirm this. Then check their local settings:

In IE11 under Internet Options -> General Tab, under the "Browsing history" section -> click the Settings button -> the Website Data Settings dialog will appear.

[image: Check for newer versions of stored pages: Automatically, or every time I visit]

"Check for newer versions of stored pages:" should be set to "Automatically" or "Every time I visit the webpage"

Alternately, you could modify your code to never cache the page(s), for example adding this to your `PageLoad` event:

```
Response.Expires = -1;
```

Comment: My next concern is "if" Never is a default setting for IE 11 installs. I haven't been able to verify it yet. But this was a new install/upgrade on the machine causing this issue. Time will tell.

Comment: I believe the default setting is "Automatically"